# Js events not getting fired inside iframe content area

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Iframe not firing clicks or any js event inside content area. I need to run given example by double clicking on content area of iframe, at the moment event can be click on border of iframe not inside content area

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <div>
        <iframe id="chart_output" ondblclick="alert('yes here')" srcdoc="<h1>HTML content</h1>">
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to anything inside an iframe (for obvious security reasons) and vice versa, which means events fired inside the iframe get propogated, but not outside the iframe, which explains why no events inside get fired. Handle the events in the iframe, or don't use an iframe at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though I need to load highchart inside iframe and container box have facility to resize, drag & double click features etc.. Any suggestion to achieve that?

Comment: @BrijeshPant why do you need to use an iframe?

Comment: we have angular page where we will have multiple chart boxes and for creating chart user can copy html/js/css from highchart fiddle and paste.. so I just injecting scripts in iframe for each.

Comment: @BrijeshPant you might want to consider something besides iframes. This will make life really hard, you know.